# SQL AVERAGE TIME

Tags: sql, datetime, time, average

I have the following query in MSSQL:

```
select 
TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID
,COUNT(TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID)AS NUMBER_OF_TRANSACTIONS
,CAST(SUM(AMOUNT)AS DECIMAL (30,2)) AS TOTAL
FROM 
    [ONLINE_TRANSACTION] 
WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(8), CREATED_ON, 114) >='17:30' AND AMOUNT IS NOT NULL AND     
TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID !='CHEQUE-STOP-TRANS-TYPE' 
GROUP BY TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID
ORDER BY TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID
```

I want to show the type of transactions `TRANSATION_TYPE_ID` as above the total amount of each type of transaction as above BUT also the average time these transactions occurred `CREATED_ON` which is `datetime` I still have not find a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Based on Randolph Potter's answer, you can find the average time like:

```
avg(DATEPART(hh,created_on)*60 + DATEPART(mi,created_on)) % 24 as AvgHour,
avg(DATEPART(hh,created_on)*60 + DATEPART(mi,created_on)) / 24 as AvgMinute
```

Comment: i found this solution aswell--> (stackoverflow.com/questions/529144/…) CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(AVG(CAST(CAST(LEFT(created_on, 12) as datetime) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME), 114) + '0'AS AVARAGE_TIME Implementing both Andomars reply and the one mentioned above i get different results.which is the correct one?

Comment: I assumed created_on was a datetime column, but then left(created_on,12) would give a syntax error.  Please edit your question and add the data type of the column, with some example rows.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to convert the time to seconds, calculate the average, and then convert it back to hours, minutes and seconds for the result.

Comment: good idea, i am sort of looking for some source code pointers thanks Randolph

Answer (score 1):

If your talking about the time of day and not looking to get a specific date, ie. 5:32 instead of Jan 4, 2012 5:32, the below could help. Sorry about the caps, it's the way I'm used to writing SQL.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,AVG(DATEPART(HH,CREATED_ON)*60 + DATEPART(MI,CREATED_ON)) / 60) + ':' + 
CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,AVG(DATEPART(HH,CREATED_ON)*60 + DATEPART(MI,CREATED_ON)) % 60) < 10
    THEN '0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,AVG(DATEPART(HH,CREATED_ON)*60 + DATEPART(MI,CREATED_ON)) % 60)
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,AVG(DATEPART(HH,CREATED_ON)*60 + DATEPART(MI,CREATED_ON)) % 60)
END AS AVG_CREATED_ON
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( ( ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP( floor(timestamp_column)) /   60 ),0) *   60 ) ) rounded_time
FROM mysql_table
WHERE timestamp_column BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('31/07/2012','%d/%m/%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('01/08/2012','%d/%m/%Y')
```