# Average time difference between sql and excel?

Tags: sql, average

I have these values of time (varchar): [hh:mm]

> ```
> 2:41
> 2:31
> 1:46
> 21:41
> 18:19
> 17:56
> 18:4
> 17:17
> 17:2
> 16:39
> 0:40
> 0:38
> 0:38
> 0:29
> 1:19
> 2:52
> 0:15
> 16:55
> 17:25
> 17:15
> 3:31
> 2:7
> 2:21
> 1:35
> 1:38
> 0:17
> 0:28
> 18:40
> 2:54
> 18:14
> 2:31
> 18:9
> 18:10
> 0:39
> 0:38
> 3:5
> 3:20
> 3:6
> 2:58
> 2:31
> 2:4
> 1:54
> 2:2
> 1:44
> 1:39
> 1:22
> 1:6
> 1:15
> 0:53
> 1:13
> 20:32
> 1:11
> 0:36
> 0:35
> 0:26
> 1:3
> 4:20
> 3:42
> 3:7
> 3:16
> 2:44
> 2:30
> 0:40
> 2:5
> 4:21
> 2:6
> 3:54
> 3:45
> 3:31
> 18:59
> 18:59
> 18:47
> 18:43
> 19:40
> 19:29
> 2:19
> 1:9
> 4:10
> 3:50
> 2:20
> 1:16
> 4:33
> 21:23
> 20:57
> 16:31
> 1:51
> 5:15
> 1:48
> 3:15
> 1:32
> 4:19
> 4:17
> 1:59
> 3:38
> 1:55
> 2:11
> 1:26
> ```

Now, when I do the average in excel the result is: `6:14`

And if I do this in sql: (using: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005782/sql-average-time))

```
select 
    Month(OperationDate) [Month], count(distinct IdOrder) OrderQty,
    avg(DATEPART(hh,TimeSpent)*60 + DATEPART(mi,TimeSpent)) % 24 as AvgHour,
    avg(DATEPART(hh,TimeSpent)*60 + DATEPART(mi,TimeSpent)) / 24 as AvgMinute

from @tmp1 tmp1
inner join tblCheckList tcl on tmp1.IdCheckList = tcl.IdCheckList
where TimeSpent<>'0:0'
group by Month(OperationDate)
```

It returns as average: `10:15`

Why the difference?

Comment: Did you check which of the two is the correct one?

Comment: How about using a `time` data type?

Comment: How to check which one is the correct one? :(

Comment: Calculate the total time an divide it by the number of time entries.

Comment: By the way, percentage char % is "modulus" and is showing the remains after a whole divide. Example 11 % 3 = 2

Comment: The correct average is 370.622 minutes, i.e. 6:10.622 (total 36321 minutes divided over 98 entries).

Comment: Correct @tripleee that's what my answer below returns `6:10` thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to work with minutes and then, convert those minutes in Hours and Minutes:

```
avg(DATEPART(hh,TimeSpent)*60 + DATEPART(mi,TimeSpent)) / 60 as AvgHour,
avg(DATEPART(hh,TimeSpent)*60 + DATEPART(mi,TimeSpent)) % 60 as AvgMinute
```

Answer (score 1):

Why `% 24` and `/ 24`?

Wouldn't you divide the average minutes by 60 to get the average hour?

```
avg(DATEPART(hh,TimeSpent)*60 + DATEPART(mi,TimeSpent)) / 60.0 as AvgHour,
avg(DATEPART(hh,TimeSpent)*60 + DATEPART(mi,TimeSpent)) as AvgMinute
```

Comment: Hi Michael, by doing this: `avg(DATEPART(hh,TimeSpent)*60 + DATEPART(mi,TimeSpent)) / 60 as AvgHour,
 avg(DATEPART(hh,TimeSpent)*60 + DATEPART(mi,TimeSpent)) / 24 as AvgMinute` I'm able to match Excel's result. So I guess, Excel's solution was the correct one, thank you.

Comment: But note, that I had to divide the AvgMinute part by 24 as well.

Comment: @Somebody But what's the reason for dividing a number of minutes by 24? I would understand dividing the hours by 24 to get the fraction of a day... but I don't understand how 24 relates to a number of minutes...

Comment: yeap, you're right, it makes no sense :(. If I leave it the way you told me, it returns: `6:370`, so why Excel returns: `6:14` ?

Comment: @Somebody Maybe Excel is just averaging the number of just the minute portion of the time... but the Sql code is converting the hours to minutes, adding the minutes... and then taking that average.

Comment: @Somebody Just curious... does `avg(DATEPART(mi,TimeSpent)) as AvgMinute` match what Excel is reporting?

Comment: I retract my comments due to movement on thin ice...sorry for that.

Comment: I agree with you, but if you look at this way, would'nt be `6:370`, would be like `11:60` cause 370 minutes are like 6 hours :(

Comment: @Somebody If we could all just switch to decimal seconds, minutes and hours... this would be much easier...

Comment: AvgMinute part reports `370` and Excel reports: `14`

Comment: @Somebody What about `avg(DATEPART(mi,TimeSpent)) as AvgMinute`?  Since this is just the minute portion, it should be less than 60...

Comment: Ok, let's think this straight, Hours and minutes are related together, I can't split them, what I can do is convert all to minutes, make the average, and then separate the result in hours and minutes. Don't you agree?

Comment: @Somebody I think that depends on what you want... do you want to look at the whole time span as a number of minutes, and then take that average... or look at just the number of minutes in the time span, ignoring the number of hours, and then take the average of just the minutes?  I can imagine scenarios where you would want one or the other.. the question is just which one you're looking for...

Comment: What I wanted is the whole time, in this case, the time is shown in hours and minutes, so we need to convert that into one of them, apply the average, and show the result in the same way of the beginning, which is hours and minutes

Answer (score 0):

This would take care of you as well.

```
Select  Convert(Varchar(5),Convert(Time,DateAdd(mi,Avg(DateDiff(mi,0,Convert(DateTime,TimeColumn))),0)))
From    TableName
```