# How can I get the average of a date field?

Tags: sql, date, average

I want to get the average of days between some dates, for example, I have a table called Patient that has the id of the registration, patient's id, entry date and final date:

```
(1,1,'07-04-2014','08-04-2014'),
(2,2,'07-04-2014','07-04-2014'),
(3,3,'08-04-2014','10-04-2014'),
(4,4,'09-04-2014','10-04-2014')
```

I want to get the average of days of the entry fields, I have tried a lot of thing but I only get random results. I tried with dtiff but it needs two arguments and I only need one.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL AVERAGE TIME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005782/sql-average-time)

Answer (score 1):

You could get the average DURATION between a fixed date and the date field. But averaging a date doesn't really make sense.

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(DD,'19700101',dateField)) AS avgDays
```

You could say the "average" date would then be: `DATEADD(DD,avgDays,'19700101')`

But I'm not sure if that makes sense in the context of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering, maybe I couldn't express what I wanted to do but I found a solution and it was actually vey simple:

select Patient.Name, avg(day(Patient.FinalDate) - day(Patient.EntryDate)) as [Average] from Patient,DetailPatient where Patient.IdPatient=DetailPatient.IdPatiene group by DetailPatient.Name

I know it looks very simple haha, but is the first time I use avg function this way.
Thank you guys.